# Sketch symbol undeline link

Tags: sketch-app

Is it possible to create a symbol for underline link so when the text changes the line width changes as well?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in text underline rather than drawing the line yourself?

I imagine that you...

1. knew about this and wanted a line you could style yourself?
2. completely missed the **Options** button (in which case, you're welcome!) :D

[image: Underline tools are under Options]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew about options button :) I didn't want to use it because the line is too close to the text.

Comment: Thought that might be the case :(  Unfortunately I don't think there's another way to do cleanly. 

Best solution I can think of is to pin the line to the bottom left/right of the symbol and manually set the width of the symbol for each instance — but that's pretty messy too :(